# Failed Ubuntu installation costs 50 GB

Tags: installation, disk-usage

I tried installing Ubuntu 11.10 on my new laptop (HP Pavilion dv6-6b20SE). I didn't want to do a complete re-install and pre-partitioning my hard disk, so I tried shrinking my main NTFS partition (which was about 620 GB + recovery and system partitions) and partitioning the unallocated space, using the Ubuntu setup.

It then showed the 50 GB I tried to shrink was unusable to allocate, so I expanded the NTFS partition back to its original size. Not wanting to give up, I tried it again. Again, it said it was unusable, so I expanded again. After rebooting, and booting up in Windows 7, I noticed about 50 GB missing from my C:/ drive. It cannot be found with disk manager or GParted.

Comment: You might want to run a file system check on W7 (aka CHDSK). If the partition really was expanded, it would, hopefully, find that space.

Answer (score 0):

Checked diskmgmt.msc? Try to install with [wubi](http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu-releases//oneiric/wubi.exe).

Answer (score 0):

To restore your missing space, use QtParted from the System Rescue CD; download here:

http://www.sysresccd.org/Download.en.php

1) Burn the ISO image to a CD.

2) Boot from the CD and hit Enter when you see the message "Boot:".

3) When you get a command prompt, enter:

`run_qtparted`

4) Select your disk on the graphical screen (most likely /dev/hda).
5) Select your NTFS partition to be resized (most likely /dev/hda1).
6) Right click with the mouse and choose Resize.
7) Set the new partition size.
8) Commit your changes in the File -> Commit menu.

If your keyboard and mouse stop responding during resizing then please just be patient.  Once your changes are saved, remove the System Rescue CD and reboot.